# How to skip code for testing or convert oracle syntax to h2

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, h2

My team and I are working with oracle database for development and production. But to save time, we decided to use H2 database for testing because it is fast.

Now we run into a problem related to SQL grammar.

```
public void lock(Collection<String> locks) {
    if (locks== null || locks.size() == 0)
        return;

    Connection dbc = null;
    Statement st = null;
    String q = null;
    try {
        dbc = db.getConnection();
        dbc.setAutoCommit(false);
        st = dbc.createStatement();
        st.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
        q = "LOCK TABLE resource_lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE";
        st.executeUpdate(q);

        // Update the lock info in DB
        List idLists = DbUtil.splitIdList(locks);
        Iterator i = idLists.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            List idList = (List) i.next();
            q =
                "DELETE FROM resource_lock\n" +
                "WHERE " + DbUtil.generateStrIn("lock", idList);
            st.executeUpdate(q);
        }

        st.close();
        st = null;
        dbc.commit();
        dbc.close();
        dbc = null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DbException(e, q);
    } finally {
        DbUtil.cleanup(log, null, st, dbc);
    }
}
```

The issue was occurred at
"LOCK TABLE resource_lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE" 
which this is oracle only grammar. In the test I wrote it always throws syntax error which states

```
Caused by: com.resource.db.DbException: Database Error: Syntax error in SQL statement "LOCK[*] TABLE RESOURCE_LOCK IN EXCLUSIVE MODE "; SQL statement:
LOCK TABLE resource_lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE [42000-160]
Last SQL was:
LOCK TABLE resource_lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

I was wondering if there are syntax for H2 that has equivalent operation.
If there isn't any then I was wondering how would I skip this section for testing since many of other classes method uses this to update the database.
I would not want the other test to fail because of this.

Comment: no offense, but how the heck do you do testing on a completely different platform than dev and production and assume that your testing is in any way valid? That's like developing and racing your car on pavement, but testing it in the ocean...

Comment: @user3659052 *It is not different platform.* You're mistaken.

Comment: And another example why it is a bad idea to test on a different DBMS than the one being used in production.

Comment: horse the reason we test in H2 is because it is fast, and we do not want test data in the production db.

Comment: yes, but you have embedded all of your SQL into a data access layer that, unless it offers interfaces for various underlying DBs, includes DBMS-specific syntax. IF you wanted to support multiple underlying platforms you needed to expose generic interfaces used by your application code which hid the underlying operations. And I won't even ask why you are, as a matter of course, locking full tables. If you have any significant user base doing concurrent transactions this is going to bite you - hard!

Comment: then if I use "SELECT * FROM .... FOR UPDATE" to lock the rows would that be feasible as to lock the entire table? as we dont have access to add additional interfaces to production code.

Comment: Row locks are better than table locks as you only have to worry about two users updating the exact same row, but still they are problematic under some circumstances - especially if you are looking to implement a connection pool where the session handle gets dropped between your SELECT and UPDATE actions as that implies abandoning the LOCK.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton since the code posted deletes rows from `resource_lock` table, I'm afraid row locking won't be enough in this case - I expect there's rows inserted for locks somehwere.

Answer (score 2):

To use different SQL commands for different DBs, you could create a DAO layer for your application:

- create an interface with methods like `deleteLock()`,
- in your application logic, use this method instead of direct SQL queries
- create multiple implementations of your DAO interface for different databases
- use "Oracle" implementation with Oracle DB, and "H2" implementation with H2

Of course there's a risk that goes with testing a different implementation than the one that will run in production, but that's what you're doing already.

---

**Example:**

MyService:

```
private LockDao lockDao;
...
public void lock(Collection<String> locks) {
    ...
    lockDao.deleteLocks(locks);
    ...
}
```

LockDao:

```
public void deleteLocks(Collection<String> locks);
```

OracleLockDao:

```
@Override
public void deleteLocks(Collection<String> locks) {
    ...
    q = "LOCK TABLE resource_lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE";
    st.executeUpdate(q);
    ...
        q =
            "DELETE FROM resource_lock\n" +
            "WHERE " + DbUtil.generateStrIn("lock", idList);
        st.executeUpdate(q);
    ...
}
```

H2LockDao:

```
@Override
public void deleteLocks(Collection<String> locks) {
    // H2 implementation of lock deletion
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly can you give an example?